# Outputting a string variable into a text file in HEX format

Tags: c++, string, file, text, hex

I'm stuck with a problem that I cannot solve.
So what i need is following: I need to make a program that receives one string input and converts it to hex and after that it saves it into a file. 
If the file isn't created, it should, but if there is one already it should continue writing to the same (i guess "a+" parameter is what i need here right? )

So an example. I execute the program. Asks me to input some words. 
I type "stack" and it returns me this "73 74 61 63 6B" which is correct.
I've done that with this algorithm

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
 string a;
 cin >> a;
 for( int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++ )
  printf( "%hX ", a[i] );
 cout << endl;
 system( "pause" );
 return 0;
}
```

That is all fine but I need that outputed in a text file. 
I used this:

```
for( int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++ ) 
     {  
      fprintf(pFile, "%hX ", a[i]); 
     }
```

But it doesn't work. Can i get help with this one, thank you!

The full code, sorry I'm having problems with code samples I hope you don't mind pastebin link
http://pastebin.com/3u1mfg8n

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not very descriptive. Can you add more details? What does it do? Nothing? Crash?

Comment: Show your code for declaration and assignment of pFile.

Comment: Sorry about that, I guess I have forgotten to. Yes, it does nothing... I will add the code in the problem on top

Comment: At first I used that code, but the hex outputting did not work correctly. I followed the instructions and only got same strings in my file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are learning C++ so why not use file streams?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main () {
  // Read your string as before
  fstream fs;
  fs.open ("hex.txt", fstream::out | fstream::app); // app = append to file
  for(int i=0; i<a.size(); ++i) 
  {  
    fs << hex << static_cast<int>(a[i]) << " ";
  }
  fs.close();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for such a quick answer. I got the same problem as my first few tries. Output for example "stack" wasn't its hex code, but it was "s t a c k".

Comment: @Juraj: I edited my answer to add the `static_cast` (I wasn't writing the code in an IDE :) Try it again.

Comment: Sure, I'll let you now in few seconds :) EDIT: awesome, this did the job! Thank you very much along to other people that tried to help!

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your code and it is working correctly. It creates a file called Personal Shop Codes.txt in the directory it is run from. I expect the problem is that your program is not being run from the directory you expect it to be run from, so your output file is merely misplaced. This can often be the case when executing your program inside an IDE.

Comment: I have copied the executable file on my desktop into a new folder and after running it it created/updated the text file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use fopen() and assign that to your FILE pointer first:

```
FILE *pFile;
pFile = fopen("output.txt","w");
```

And then close the file when your program has finished writing to it:

```
fclose(pFile);
```

Comment: I have done that, sorry for a little misunderstanding. I updated my problem question few seconds later and added the pastebin link to it: http://pastebin.com/3u1mfg8n

Comment: When I strip that example to only what you want it seems to work perfectly: http://pastebin.com/9rELapSr

Answer (score -1):

This will convert each byte in the string (each character that is) into its 2-character hex encoding:

```
for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
{
    printf("%2.2X ", a[i]);
}
```

If you want to store it:

```
std::string b = "";
for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i)
{
    char tmp[3] = {0};
    sprintf(tmp, "%2.2X", a[i]);
    b += tmp;
}
```

Then you can write the entire `b` string out to the file easily.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to run it! But the thing is my code works except that i need those outputs in the text file.